# Links not clickabe in CodeIgniter 3.0.3

Tags: codeigniter

I am confused why this link is not clickable or nothing happens in chrome, and in mozilla returns error something like 'address wasn't understood'...

HTML markup exactly is this

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('makers/create_makers')?>">Add new Makers</a></li>
```

which in turn, produce something like

```
   <li><a href="localhost:8089/makers/create_makers">Add new Makers</a></li>
```

The weird part is adding 'index'

```
    <li><a href="localhost:8089/makers/create_makers/index">Add new Makers</a></li>//works
```

Which means I have to add 'index' in every link created in order to work

Controller

```
  public function create_makers()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Add New Car Maker';
    $data['content'] = 'makers/create_makers';
    $data2['content']='makers/success';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','description','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nation_id','nation_id','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) 
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/layout', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->makers_model->new_makers();

        $this->load->view('templates/layout',$data2');
    }

}
```

Inside config/config.php

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'localhost:8089';
  $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';//remove or not remove same still not working
```

routes

```
$route['makers/create_makers'] = 'makers/create_makers';
$route['default_controller'] = 'services/index';
```

.htaccess is put inside root folder(outside application folder)

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I also tried to remove htaccess and put inside application folder but nothings happen when clicking the link

However if I manually add a trailing 'index', this will work.

```
 localhost:8089/makers/create_makers//doesn't work
 localhost:8089/makers/create_makers/index //works!
```

I am confuse about this in Codeigniter

Inside apache

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/
    #AcceptPathInfo On
    <Directory /var/www/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/>
      Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/application/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/application/logs/access.log combined
```

mod_rewrite is enabled

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have mod_rewrite activated?

Comment: @Mario Cesar, yes already activited.I use Vagrant and ubuntu trusty for this in development in windows machine..Maybe it is related to vagrant boxes? I follow carefully Codeigniter docs but dont know why this not work

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'localhost:8089'; Needs protocol  - http:// , you cant just put localhost..

Comment: Tried.But the error is  404

Comment: only works when I add 'index' after the 'localhost:8089/makers/create_makers'

Comment: That usually indicates a .htaccess problem. I don't know enough of apache config to help you, but it looks like your http por is 8089, but you have <VirtualHost *:80>? Again, I don't know much of apache config.

Comment: I am using vagrant for this in development, and I have no trouble with in my Symfony or Laravel projects.the http port 8089 comes from the vagrantfile configuration I created, which, again, I have no trouble when using Symfony or laravel  "config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8089".Maybe this indicates a .htaccess problem in Codeigniter root file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets tweak your .htaccess and see if it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
 AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

And remove index.php in your config file

```
$config['index_php']='';
```

And according to the codigniter docs

> A URL containing the word “journals” in the first segment will be remapped to the “blogs” class.

```
$route['journals'] = 'blogs';
```

so lets apply this in your route file

```
$route['makers/new_makers'] = 'makers/create_makers';
```

Now your link will work without appending 'index' ..Something like

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('makers/new_makers')?>">Add new Makers</a></li>
```

Remember, url inside $route[''] should mapped to a class and its method.In this case the url

```
<?php echo site_url('makers/new_makers') ?>
```

Will look to the controller Makers and its method

```
 create_makers()
```

which then render the view that contains create_makers.php inside the makers folder in your view folder.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to load the url helper in the autoload file or in the construct of the controller.

Your url should look like this:

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:8089/makers/create_makers">Add new Makers</a></li>
```

If you don't have the http:// it won't work.

In addtion, you have to leave the `$config['base_url']` blank and `$config['index_page']`.

Comment: site_url() automatically render http:// in html.So the problem now is how to make it work without adding 'index' in the url  <li><a href="http://localhost:8089/makers/create_makers/index">Add new Makers</a></li>

Comment: Leave the $config['base_url'] and $config['index_page']  blank. Also eliminate this route $route['makers/create_makers'] = 'makers/create_makers'; it is pointing to the same thing, so there is no need to have it.

Comment: this doesnt work either.Auto guessing will redirect the link to an ipAddress something like http://10.0.2.15/makers/create_makers which doesn't exists .

Comment: Is the makers controller the one that builds the current page?.

Comment: yes, method create_makers() is called inside Makers class(controller makers.php)